# GridView SelectCommand missing WHERE at runtime

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, gridview

I've got a GridView.  My SelectCommand in the code works if I copy and paste it into SQL Server Management Studio.  It executes fine.

If I run the page and click Edit for any row I get the error:

> "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IS'."

I've tried to see what's going on using SQL Server Profiler.  Here's what the SelectCommand looks like and what SQL is receiving...

SelectCommand from supplies.ascx

```
SELECT some stuff FROM here WHERE (this IS NULL) and (that=1) ORDER BY this DESC
```

SQL Server Profiler reports

```
SELECT some stuff FROM here (this IS NULL) and (that=1) ORDER BY this DESC
```

I didn't put any code here because I'm not really sure what would be relevant and didn't want to load up the post with unnecessary lines of code.  Please let me know what you'd like to see to help.

Requested code below.  I didn't put everything from the GridView in...It's pretty big.  If needed though I can update.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="fldSupReqID"
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
                EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display." AllowSorting="True" 
                CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" Font-Size="10px">
                <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>"
                DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [tblSupplyRequests] WHERE [fldSupReqID] = @fldSupReqID"
                InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [tblSupplyRequests] ([fldManufacturerID], [fldItemID], [fldFeeTypeID], [fldRequestDate], [fldStamp], [fldAddedByUser], [fldBID]) VALUES (@fldManufacturerID, @fldItemID, @fldFeeTypeID, @fldRequestDate, @fldStamp, @fldAddedByUser, @fldBID)"       




                ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT tblSupplyRequests.fldSupReqID, tblSupplyRequests.fldOrderToShipDate, tblSupplyRequests.fldBID AS BID, tblMerchantIDs.fldMerchantID AS MerchantID, salescontactinfo.sname_of_business AS [Merchant Name], salescontactinfo.scontactname1 AS Contact, salescontactinfo.scontactn1phone1 AS Phone, tblSupplyRequests.fldRequestDate, tblSupplyRequests.fldAddedByUser AS RequestedBy, INVtblManufacturers.fldManufacturerName AS [Term Manuf], INVtblInventoryItems_1.fldItemName AS [Term Model], INVtblInventoryTypes.fldInventoryTypename AS [Item Type], tblSupplyRequests.fldNumItemsRequested AS [Num Items], tblSupplyRequests.fldPaperItemID, tblSupplyRequests.fldPerItemCost, INVtblInventoryItems.fldMiscDesc, tblSupplyRequests.fldPersonCalling, tblSupplyRequests.fldTitlePersonCalling, tblSupplyRequests.fldNotes, salescontactinfo.sstate, tblSupplyRequests.fldManufacturerID, tblSupplyRequests.fldItemID, tblSupplyRequests.fldStamp, tblSupplyRequests.fldOrderToShipDate AS Expr1, tblSupplyRequests.fldOrderToShipBy FROM INVtblInventoryItems INNER JOIN tblSupplyRequests INNER JOIN salescontactinfo ON tblSupplyRequests.fldBID = salescontactinfo.sbusinessid LEFT OUTER JOIN tblMerchantIDs ON salescontactinfo.sbusinessid = tblMerchantIDs.fldBID LEFT OUTER JOIN INVtblManufacturers ON tblSupplyRequests.fldManufacturerID = INVtblManufacturers.fldManufacturerID ON INVtblInventoryItems.fldItemID = tblSupplyRequests.fldPaperItemID LEFT OUTER JOIN INVtblInventoryTypes ON tblSupplyRequests.fldInventoryTypeID = INVtblInventoryTypes.fldInventoryTypeID LEFT OUTER JOIN INVtblInventoryItems AS INVtblInventoryItems_1 ON tblSupplyRequests.fldItemID = INVtblInventoryItems_1.fldItemID WHERE (tblSupplyRequests.fldOrderToShipDate IS NULL) AND (tblMerchantIDs.fldMIDStatusID=1) ORDER BY tblSupplyRequests.fldRequestDate DESC"                   




                UpdateCommand="UPDATE tblSupplyRequests SET fldOrderToShipDate=@fldOrderToShipDate, fldNotes = @fldNotes, fldTitlePersonCalling = @fldTitlePersonCalling, fldPersonCalling = @fldPersonCalling, fldRequestDate = @fldRequestDate WHERE (fldSupReqID = @fldSupReqID)">
                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="fldSupReqID" Type="Int32" />
                </DeleteParameters>
                <InsertParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="fldManufacturerID" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="fldItemID" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="fldFeeTypeID" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="fldRequestDate" Type="DateTime" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="fldStamp" Type="DateTime" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="fldAddedByUser" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="fldBID" Type="Int32" />
                </InsertParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="fldOrderToShipDate" Type="DateTime" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="fldNotes" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="fldTitlePersonCalling" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="fldPersonCalling" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="fldRequestDate" Type="DateTime" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="fldSupReqID" Type="Int32" />
                </UpdateParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And here's what SQL Server Profiler catches...

```
SELECT tblSupplyRequests.fldSupReqID, tblSupplyRequests.fldOrderToShipDate, tblSupplyRequests.fldBID AS BID, tblMerchantIDs.fldMerchantID AS MerchantID, salescontactinfo.sname_of_business AS [Merchant Name], salescontactinfo.scontactname1 AS Contact, salescontactinfo.scontactn1phone1 AS Phone, tblSupplyRequests.fldRequestDate, tblSupplyRequests.fldAddedByUser AS RequestedBy, INVtblManufacturers.fldManufacturerName AS [Term Manuf], INVtblInventoryItems_1.fldItemName AS [Term Model], INVtblInventoryTypes.fldInventoryTypename AS [Item Type], tblSupplyRequests.fldNumItemsRequested AS [Num Items], tblSupplyRequests.fldPaperItemID, tblSupplyRequests.fldPerItemCost, INVtblInventoryItems.fldMiscDesc, tblSupplyRequests.fldPersonCalling, tblSupplyRequests.fldTitlePersonCalling, tblSupplyRequests.fldNotes, salescontactinfo.sstate, tblSupplyRequests.fldManufacturerID, tblSupplyRequests.fldItemID, tblSupplyRequests.fldStamp, tblSupplyRequests.fldOrderToShipDate AS Expr1, tblSupplyRequests.fldOrderToShipBy FROM INVtblInventoryItems INNER JOIN tblSupplyRequests INNER JOIN salescontactinfo ON tblSupplyRequests.fldBID = salescontactinfo.sbusinessid LEFT OUTER JOIN tblMerchantIDs ON salescontactinfo.sbusinessid = tblMerchantIDs.fldBID LEFT OUTER JOIN INVtblManufacturers ON tblSupplyRequests.fldManufacturerID = INVtblManufacturers.fldManufacturerID ON INVtblInventoryItems.fldItemID = tblSupplyRequests.fldPaperItemID LEFT OUTER JOIN INVtblInventoryTypes ON tblSupplyRequests.fldInventoryTypeID = INVtblInventoryTypes.fldInventoryTypeID LEFT OUTER JOIN INVtblInventoryItems AS INVtblInventoryItems_1 ON tblSupplyRequests.fldItemID = INVtblInventoryItems_1.fldItemID  (tblSupplyRequests.fldOrderToShipDate IS NULL) AND (tblMerchantIDs.fldMIDStatusID=1) ORDER BY tblSupplyRequests.fldRequestDate DESC
```

Comment: can you post some code? how do you bind data to gridview, datasource, html?

Comment: It's probably *very* related to your actual SQL query (like you're using reserved words or some-such-tom-foolery).  Can you post that?

Comment: `WHERE` is missing from your select statement

Answer (score 0):

I hate to say this, but it could just be that ASP.NET is parsing the query incorrectly because of all the nested `INNER JOIN`s that precede it all on one line.  I wonder if formatting your SQL would help at all?  There is a very cool tool online for [neatly formatting your SQL statements](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm).

Here's the formatted version of your `SQLDataSource`:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>"
    DeleteCommand=" DELETE FROM [tblSupplyRequests] 
                    WHERE  [fldSupReqID] = @fldSupReqID"
    InsertCommand=" INSERT INTO [tblSupplyRequests] ([fldManufacturerID],[fldItemID],[fldFeeTypeID],[fldRequestDate],[fldStamp],[fldAddedByUser],[fldBID]) 
                    VALUES (@fldManufacturerID,@fldItemID,@fldFeeTypeID,@fldRequestDate,@fldStamp,@fldAddedByUser,@fldBID)"       
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
    SelectCommand=" SELECT tblsupplyrequests.fldsupreqid, 
                           tblsupplyrequests.fldordertoshipdate, 
                           tblsupplyrequests.fldbid                  AS bid, 
                           tblmerchantids.fldmerchantid              AS merchantid, 
                           salescontactinfo.sname_of_business        AS [Merchant Name], 
                           salescontactinfo.scontactname1            AS contact, 
                           salescontactinfo.scontactn1phone1         AS phone, 
                           tblsupplyrequests.fldrequestdate, 
                           tblsupplyrequests.fldaddedbyuser          AS requestedby, 
                           invtblmanufacturers.fldmanufacturername   AS [Term Manuf], 
                           invtblinventoryitems_1.flditemname        AS [Term Model], 
                           invtblinventorytypes.fldinventorytypename AS [Item Type], 
                           tblsupplyrequests.fldnumitemsrequested    AS [Num Items], 
                           tblsupplyrequests.fldpaperitemid, 
                           tblsupplyrequests.fldperitemcost, 
                           invtblinventoryitems.fldmiscdesc, 
                           tblsupplyrequests.fldpersoncalling, 
                           tblsupplyrequests.fldtitlepersoncalling, 
                           tblsupplyrequests.fldnotes, 
                           salescontactinfo.sstate, 
                           tblsupplyrequests.fldmanufacturerid, 
                           tblsupplyrequests.flditemid, 
                           tblsupplyrequests.fldstamp, 
                           tblsupplyrequests.fldordertoshipdate      AS expr1, 
                           tblsupplyrequests.fldordertoshipby 
                    FROM   invtblinventoryitems 
                           INNER JOIN tblsupplyrequests 
                                      INNER JOIN salescontactinfo 
                                        ON tblsupplyrequests.fldbid = salescontactinfo.sbusinessid 
                                      LEFT OUTER JOIN tblmerchantids 
                                        ON salescontactinfo.sbusinessid = tblmerchantids.fldbid 
                                      LEFT OUTER JOIN invtblmanufacturers 
                                        ON tblsupplyrequests.fldmanufacturerid = invtblmanufacturers.fldmanufacturerid 
                             ON invtblinventoryitems.flditemid = tblsupplyrequests.fldpaperitemid 
                           LEFT OUTER JOIN invtblinventorytypes 
                             ON tblsupplyrequests.fldinventorytypeid = invtblinventorytypes.fldinventorytypeid 
                           LEFT OUTER JOIN invtblinventoryitems AS invtblinventoryitems_1 
                             ON tblsupplyrequests.flditemid = invtblinventoryitems_1.flditemid 
                    WHERE  ( tblsupplyrequests.fldordertoshipdate IS NULL ) 
                           AND ( tblmerchantids.fldmidstatusid = 1 ) 
                    ORDER  BY tblsupplyrequests.fldrequestdate DESC"
    UpdateCommand=" UPDATE tblsupplyrequests 
                    SET    fldordertoshipdate = @fldOrderToShipDate, 
                           fldnotes = @fldNotes, 
                           fldtitlepersoncalling = @fldTitlePersonCalling, 
                           fldpersoncalling = @fldPersonCalling, 
                           fldrequestdate = @fldRequestDate 
                    WHERE  ( fldsupreqid = @fldSupReqID )" >
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="fldSupReqID" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="fldManufacturerID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="fldItemID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="fldFeeTypeID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="fldRequestDate" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="fldStamp" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="fldAddedByUser" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="fldBID" Type="Int32" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="fldOrderToShipDate" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="fldNotes" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="fldTitlePersonCalling" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="fldPersonCalling" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="fldRequestDate" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="fldSupReqID" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

*Note: if your queries in the SQLDataSource are getting this complex, you may want to consider moving this logic into a class / data access layer for future maintainability.  Having said that, I understand that sometimes you are stuck with what you have for the time-being =)  Good luck!*